# If $\Delta u=0, \text{then}\, \exists v \ni \Delta v=0$ with $u$ and $v$ are harmonic functions.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, harmonic-functions

[image]

Could you please explain to me how we get the last integral?

Comment: The last integral is just the definition of $v$ in 2.31.

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers. – For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: As a minor but necessary point that is glossed over in the text and the chosen answer, since $\Omega$ is open in a metric space, we can choose an $|h|$ small enough so that the image of $\gamma_h$ lies within $\Omega$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the definition, $v(x,y) = \int_\gamma - \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}dx + \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}dy$, where $\gamma$ is any path between $p$ an $(x,y)$. Denoting $\gamma_{(x,y)}$ to emphasize the point, one can get
$$
v(x+h,y) - v(x,y) = \left(\int_{\gamma_{(x+h,y)}} - \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}dx + \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}dy\right) - \left(\int_{\gamma_{(x,y)}} - \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}dx + \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}dy\right) = \\ =
\left(\int_{\gamma_{(x+h,y)}} - \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}dx + \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}dy\right) + \left(\int_{-\gamma_{(x,y)}} - \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}dx + \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}dy\right) = 
\int_{\gamma_{(x+h,y)}-\gamma_{(x,y)}} - \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}dx + \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}dy
$$
where the last equality is due to additivity of line integral. As
$\gamma_{(x+h,y)}$ is some path from $p$ to $(x+h,y)$ and $-\gamma_{(x,y)}$ is a path from $(x,y)$ to $p$, it follows that $\gamma_{(x+h,y)} - \gamma_{(x,y)}$ is a path from $(x,y)$ to $(x+h,y)$. As all pathes are arbitrary, we the path from $(x,y)$ to $(x+h,y)$ to be $\gamma_h(t) = (x+th, y)$ as it defined in the given theorem.